# JAVA: Using an array to define the X position and movement of an object on screen

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a problem with code I'm writing for a simple game - I am trying to make an array determine the position of an object on screen after a collision.

The code functions fine without the array and loop and neither the loop or array show syntactical errors.

Can anyone see the problem?

```
if (mBallSpeedY >0 || mBallSpeedY < 100) {
    if (nMinDistanceBetweenBallAndSmiley >= distanceBetweenBallAndSmiley) {
        float speedOfBall = (float) Math.sqrt(mBallSpeedX * mBallSpeedX + mBallSpeedY * mBallSpeedY);

        mBallSpeedX = mBallX - mSmileyX;
        mBallSpeedY = mBallY - mSmiley.getWidth() / 2;

        float newSpeedOfReboundBall = (float) Math.sqrt(mBallSpeedX * mBallSpeedX + mBallSpeedY * mBallSpeedY);

        mBallSpeedX = mBallSpeedX * speedOfBall / newSpeedOfReboundBall;
        mBallSpeedY = mBallSpeedY * speedOfBall / newSpeedOfReboundBall;
        updateScore(5);

       int[] smileyXPositions = new int[15];

        smileyXPositions[0] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*2;
        smileyXPositions[1] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*3;
        smileyXPositions[2] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*4;
        smileyXPositions[3] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*5;
        smileyXPositions[4] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*6;
        smileyXPositions[5] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*7;
        smileyXPositions[6] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*8;
        smileyXPositions[7] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*9;
        smileyXPositions[8] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*8;
        smileyXPositions[9] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*7;
        smileyXPositions[10] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*6;
        smileyXPositions[11] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*5;
        smileyXPositions[12] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*4;
        smileyXPositions[13] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*3;
        smileyXPositions[14] = (mCanvasWidth /10)*2;
        smileyXPositions[15] = mCanvasWidth /10;

        mSmileyX = smileyXPositions[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < smileyXPositions.length; i++)
        {
            if(smileyXPositions[i]>15)
            {
              smileyXPositions[15] = smileyXPositions[i];
            }

        else if(smileyXPositions[i]<0)
            {
          smileyXPositions[0] = smileyXPositions[i];
            }

    }

        }
```

(I'm a beginner so I assume it will be something basic)?

Comment: please post the code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If your array should have indexes from 0 to 15 you need an array with 16 entries:

```
int[] smileyXPositions = new int[16];
```

Comment: Exactly 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15 clearTest.Main.main(Main.java:23)`